# Matter of customizing Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm stuck in make table of contents like this. I found some topic about add vertical rule next to Chapter. But I can't find how to add dot at begin of line like this.
Please help me, thank you all!!
[image]

I'm using code I found on other posts in this forum.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{report}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
    
\newcommand*{\numberwithbar}[2]{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{.1pt}{\baselineskip}\hspace{#1}#2}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entrynumberformat=\numberwithbar{.5em}]{tocline}{section}
    \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent:=section,numwidth=4em,entrynumberformat=\numberwithbar{1.5em}]{tocline}{subsection}
\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Project Introduction}
    \section{Section A}
    \section{subsection A}
    
    \chapter{Case Study 2}
    \section{Section A}
    \section{Section B}
    \section{Section C}
    \section{Section D}
    \subsection{subsection A}
    \subsection{subsection A}
    
\end{document}
```

Current result:

[image: current]

Comment: please add the code which led you to this output

Comment: @Durtle, so what's your code which produces your (current) screenshot? Without knowing that answers can only be "just add those dots ...", which isn't too helpful, is it? Remember, Latex provides many ways to achieve the same or similar print ... which route did you take?

Comment: I just edit my question, thank you all

Comment: Hm, two problems: 1) package tocbasic is intended for komascript classes, so there may or may not be unwanted side effects (use class scrreprt instead). 2) What your code creates isn't too close to what you seem to want, in my view.

Comment: Hmm, I got it. I'm sorry because I see the TOC in picture in another document. I want to make a TOC like that but I only found the code not close to what I want :((((

Comment: Assuming you are new to Latex, I suggest to put that problem aside for now and work with the standard toc. And who knows, perhaps you'll start to like it. However, the more you do in Latex, the easier it will be for you to work with packages, like etoc: https://ftp.rrze.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/etoc/etoc.pdf .

Comment: thank you very much!